# Is there such a thing as an array/object hybrid?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I'm using an npm module called [horseman](https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman) which is basically PhantomJS for Node. When I console log the contents of a horseman object it has all sorts of data about the current page. Included in all this data is a list of all the resources of a page and their http status codes like this:

```
responses: [ 'http://tylertrotter.com/': 301,
  'http://www.tylertrotter.com/': 200,
  'http://www.tylertrotter.com/css/main.css': 200, 
  ...
]
```

It looks like an array/object hybrid and I've never encountered something like this before. `Array.isArray(responses)` yields `true` but `responses.length` turns up with `0`.

What is this thing?

Full console log of entire horseman object here: https://gist.github.com/tylertrotter/be8da3e777c16a2b631d9de9fc94f70b

Comment: Is this a JavaScript question or a horseman question? I would imagine that they monkey-patched the .toString method

Comment: Could you please paste the output of: `console.log(responses)`

Comment: @webdeb I've added the entire object. `responses` starts on line 29.

Comment: @tylertrotter found your gist and the issue at horseman, good catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there such *a* thing? No, *every* array is this thing.

`Array`s are just a special type of object in JS (like `RegExp` or `Date` instances), and they can have arbitrary properties assigned to them. Of course, a for loop will only consider its `.length` and iterate integer indices, but that doesn't prevent the object from containing anything. `console.log` typically does show such arrays in the style you have spotted.

It should be noted however that abusing arrays like this [is considered a very bad practise](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/). You should file a bug with the module and tell them to use objects are even better [`Map`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as collections.

Comment: Okay cool, I didn't know you could abuse arrays this way. I'll file a bug and see what he says.